# Активация кнопки из кастомной библиотеки при помощи Enter

Tags: c#, winforms

Есть библиотека Bunifu.
Как присвоить включение кастомной кнопки из стандартного textbox по нажатию Enter?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Может, наоборот: `this.AcceptButton = this.bunifuThinButton;`

Comment: не работает, пробовал.